# Matplotlib reads jpg into int8 and png into normalized float

Tags: python, matplotlib

Why do Matplotlib load .png into float32 (from 0 to 1):

```
img = mpimg.imread('some.png')
print(img.dtype)
>>> float32
```

and .jpg to int8 (from 0 to 255):

```
img = mpimg.imread('some.jpg')
print(img.dtype)
>>> int8
```

Why? On the basis of what considerations is it realized this way?

Comment: @DanMašek thanks, same method names is quite confusing :)

Comment: Anyway, my guess would be that it's probably due to the library using an internal implementation to load the PNG, while for everything else it uses the PIL library. (As the docs mention) | If you have OpenCV available, then might as well use its `imread`, which AFAIK is consistent.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As the [`imread` documenation](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imread.html) states:

> matplotlib can only read PNGs natively, but if PIL is installed, it will use it to load the image and return an array (if possible) [...]

So for `png` images, matplotlib has its own code to read the image, while for `jpg` it relies on `PIL`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im = plt.imread("house.png")
print im.dtype               # float32

im = plt.imread("house.jpg")
print im.dtype               # uint8
```

The internal `_png` module which is responsible for loading the `png` image, has two functions, `read_png_float` and `read_png_int`. While by default `read_png_float` is used, you may as well manually use `read_png_int` to obtain an integer image.

```
import matplotlib._png as png

im = png.read_png_float("house.png")
print im.dtype              # float32

im = png.read_png_int("house.png")
print im.dtype              # uint8
```

Finally, for a consistent behaviour you may use `PIL` for both, `png` and `jpg` images instead of relying on matplotlib.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

im = np.asarray(Image.open("house.png"))
print im.dtype              # uint8

im = np.asarray(Image.open("house.jpg"))
print im.dtype              # uint8
```

Comment: I can't find any documentation about the method *read_png_int()* at all. Do you know anywhere to read a little more about it? It seems to be quite a bit faster to execute than *np.asarray(Image.open("house.png"))*. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In Matplotlib 3.xx, there is no read_png_int() method any more. But we can use following way to handle png file.

```
from PIL import Image
from numpy import asarray
test_pic="image.png"
image=Image.open(test_pic)
img=asarray(image) 

print(img)

[[ 91 108  98]
 [ 99 116 106]
 [107 124 116]
 ...
 [  1   5   8]
 [  1   5   8]
 [  1   5   8]]
```